# IIS Log Details for Dynamic CRM SDK Calls

Tags: iis, dynamics-crm, iis-logs

I have taken IIS logs for CRM OrganizationService for Performance check and I am getting logs like

```
+OnBeginRequest:06/07/2017-06:06:22.941+SdkB(Create:10232):06:06:22.944+SdkE:06:07:26.204+LogEntries:0+SDKSqlCalls:11+SDKSqlCallsMs:63235+GC:10130+LogEntries:0+SqlCalls:0+SqlCallsMs:0+GC:10130+OnEndRequest:06:07:26.206

+OnBeginRequest:06/07/2017-06:02:18.508+SdkB(Update:2):06:02:18.512+SdkB(RetrieveMultiple:150):06:02:18.533+SdkE:06:02:18.539+LogEntries:0+SDKSqlCalls:1+SDKSqlCallsMs:1+GC:10121+SdkB(Retrieve:8):06:02:18.542+SdkE:06:02:18.545+LogEntries:0+SDKSqlCalls:1+SDKSqlCallsMs:1+GC:10121+SdkB(RetrieveMultiple:10254):06:02:18.546+SdkE:06:02:18.556+LogEntries:0+SDKSqlCalls:1+SDKSqlCallsMs:8+GC:10121+SdkB(RetrieveMultiple:10250):06:02:18.558+SdkE:06:02:18.571+LogEntries:0+SDKSqlCalls:1+SDKSqlCallsMs:1+GC:10121+SdkB(RetrieveMultiple:10250):06:02:18.583+SdkE:06:02:18.635+LogEntries:0+SDKSqlCalls:1+SDKSqlCallsMs:1+GC:10121+SdkB(RetrieveMultiple:2):06:02:18.704+SdkE:06:02:18.713+LogEntries:0+SDKSqlCalls:1+SDKSqlCallsMs:2+GC:10121+SdkB(RetrieveMultiple:10250):06:02:18.717+SdkE:06:02:18.722+LogEntries:0+SDKSqlCalls:1+SDKSqlCallsMs:1+GC:10121+SdkB(RetrieveMultiple:1):06:02:18.724+SdkE:06:02:18.745+LogEntries:0+SDKSqlCalls:1+SDKSqlCallsMs:6+GC:10121+SdkB(Retrieve:10221):06:02:18.748+SdkE:06:02:18.758+LogEntries:0+SDKSqlCalls:1+SDKSqlCallsMs:2+GC:10121+SdkE:06:02:33.802+LogEntries:0+SDKSqlCalls:8+SDKSqlCallsMs:15023+GC:10122+LogEntries:0+SqlCalls:0+SqlCallsMs:0+GC:10122+OnEndRequest:06:02:33.803
```

I am not able to interpret the Parameters in this cs-uri-query field. I have seen some blogs but they did not mention each fields' (ex: SdkE) importance. Please can somebody help with fields.